# How can I utilize the animated link hover state I'm using, along with Bootstrap's stretched link?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a situation where I've decorated a link's hover state and added an animated underline to the link.

I'm using absolute position as part of that CSS. The issue is `bottom: 0;` in the `::after` pseudo class.

At the same time, I also want to use Bootstrap's stretched link, which uses `top: 0;` in the `stretched-link::after` pseudo class.

If I use the `stretched-link` class on the button, my link hover state applies, but the animated line appears on top of the linked item, and not under as I would like it to.

It's created a competing issue and I don't understand the best way to overcome it.

**Traditional Bootstrap 5 Card w/ `stretched-link` applied:**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card my-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/400x50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Traditional Bootstrap 5 Card w/ `stretched-link` and my animated hover state applied:**

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
}

.container p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #005fec;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #005fec;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

a:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 1px solid #005fec;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card my-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/400x50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to work around the sizing issue is to add an element with relative positioning to control the pseudo-element. I'm using a span inside the anchor.

I'd also avoid styling entire element types. Use a custom class or any more specific selector to prevent unintended consequences elsewhere.

Finally, know that outlines are an important accessibility feature. Don't remove them unless you have a suitable replacement for those navigating your site by keyboard, for example.

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
}

.container p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a.fancy-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #005fec;
  outline: 0;
}

a.fancy-underline span {
  position: relative;
}

a.fancy-underline span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #005fec;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

a.fancy-underline:hover span::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

a:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 1px solid #005fec;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card my-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/400x50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>

          <a href="#" class="stretched-link fancy-underline">
            <span>Go somewhere</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```